# How to extend a Boto3 resource?

Tags: python, boto, boto3, botocore

On boto3, how can I extend `ResourceModel`? What I wan't to do is subclass `boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Instance` and add a `run` method to it. That method would be used to remotely run commands on the EC2 instance represented by the Python object, via SSH. I wish to do this in a clean way, i.e., without resorting to monkey patches or other obscure techniques.

**Update**

Based on [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29637081), I came up with the following code. Requires a recent version of Boto 3, and [Spur](https://github.com/mwilliamson/spur.py) for the SSH connection (`pip install spur boto3`).

```
from boto3 import session
from shlex import split
from spur import SshShell

# Customize here.
REGION = 'AWS-REGION'
INSTID = 'AWS-INSTANCE-ID'
USERID = 'SSH-USER'

def hook_ssh(class_attributes, **kwargs):
    def run(self, command):
        '''Run a command on the EC2 instance via SSH.'''

        # Create the SSH client.
        if not hasattr(self, '_ssh_client'):
            self._ssh_client = SshShell(self.public_ip_address, USERID)

        print(self._ssh_client.run(split(command)).output.decode())

    class_attributes['run'] = run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b3s = session.Session()
    ec2 = b3s.resource('ec2', region_name=REGION)

    # Hook the "run" method to the "ec2.Instance" resource class.
    b3s.events.register('creating-resource-class.ec2.Instance', hook_ssh)

    # Run some commands.
    ec2.Instance(INSTID).run('uname -a')
    ec2.Instance(INSTID).run('uptime')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that this isn't yet possible but it is planned to allow customizations of this sort. You can already see them in action with the new `upload_file` and `download_file` customization available on the S3 client. The plan is to use that same sort of mechanism for Boto 3 resources.

1. Resources will fire some kind of event when creating a class that includes the attribute dict of all methods/attributes
2. You hook your own method into the attribute dict
3. The class gets created with your custom method - no monkey-patching required.

Take a look here:

https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/session.py#L314-L318
https://github.com/boto/boto3/tree/develop/boto3/s3

Boto 3 extensibility is definitely on our radar.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I wrote some code basing on the resources you gave. I'll try to run it when boto3 is ready.

Comment: This topic is covered in the boto3 docs now under the [Extensibility Guide](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/events.html).

Comment: Thanks Ben. I've updated the question with a runnable code snippet and will accept this answer.

Comment: Also I wrote [a blog post](https://whaletech.co/2015/09/25/extending-boto3.html) about my experience using it so far. May prove useful to others.